# Spring controller method shared my multiple @RequestMapping urls with different parameters

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have added the following method to the OwnerController class in [the Spring PetClinic sample application](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic/):

```
//'''''''''CodeMed added this next method
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/catowners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwnersOfPetType(Map<String, Object> model) {
    // find owners of a specific type of pet
    Integer typeID = 1;//this is just a placeholder
    Collection<Owner> results = this.clinicService.findOwnerByPetType(typeID);
    model.put("selections", results);
    return "owners/catowners";
 }
//'''''''''''''''''''
```

Since the typeID for cats in the petclinic database is 1, the above returns a list of cat owners.  But I also want to create separate pages on the site for dog owners, lizard owners, hamster owners, and owners of any other kind of pet.  Do I need to create a separate version of findOwnersOfPetType() for each pet type?  Like findDogOwners(), findLizardOwners(), findHamsterOwners(), etc.?  Or can I have the findOwnersOfPetType() method accept an int parameter indicating the pet type?

What about jsp files?  Do I need to create a separate jsp file for each of catowners.jsp, dogowners.jsp, lizardowners.jsp, hamsterowners.jsp, etc.?  Or can I somehow create one jsp that is populated with different data in the same format for each type of pet?

How would this look in code?

The ClinicService and OwnerRepository functions are already handled together because the function I posted above calls a ClinicService method using a parameter created in the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `RequestMapping` with a `PathVariable`.  For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwnersOfPetType(Map<String, Object> model,
    @PathVariable int petId) {
    //use id as before
}
```

If you want to use strings in your URLs instead of integers, you can make them more user friendly by using Strings in the URLs instead and having an enum mapping between those Strings and their IDs.

Comment: Please also expand on how the returned view name and jsp will be affected. Assuming we have `DogOwner`, `CatOwner`, `LizardOwner`.

Comment: The view name is generally dependant on if you need separate JSPs to display different types of pet owners.  If you need separate JSPs, then you can easily map parameters to Views in the same manner as you would map strings to Ids (enums).  But you should really be able to just have a single reasonably generic JSP.  In the end that's really driven by your data model and I don't have enough information on that to really comment.

Comment: @Aurand Thank you.  +1 for trying to help.  The entire data model, and the entire application code, are located at the link to the github petclinic page at the top of my post above.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a type parameter to your request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{type}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwnersOfPetType(@PathVariable("type") it type) {

}
```

So you don't need different controller methods for handling multiple types.

The service method depends on how you model your domain objects. If you have a single class `Pet` which contains a `petType` you could easily do something like this:

```
Collection<Owner> results = this.clinicService.findOwnerByPetType(type);
```

The service then calls the repository method `findOwnerByPetType(type)` which returns the list of owners

Comment: Please also expand on how the returned view name and jsp will be affected. Assuming we have `DogOwner`, `CatOwner`, `LizardOwner`.

Comment: Can you post your domain model for this? I think a single `Pet` class with a `petType` should not be able to have different types of owners. It would be possible that a pet with type `dog` would have a `CatOwner`.

Comment: @micha The domain model, and the entire application code, is located at the link to the petclinic github page at the top of my original posting above.  +1 for trying to help.  Thank you.